# Decryption from encryption method

Tags: delphi, encryption

I am needing to re-write a decryption method for an old piece of code, unfortunately the original decryption method has been lost on we only have access to the encryption.

```
type
  TintArray = array [0 .. 1] of Cardinal;
  TKeyArray = Array [0 .. 3] of Cardinal;

const
  KeyArray: TKeyArray = (858945348, 1144282739, 828794915, 556884274);

  procedure Encipher(var V, W: TintArray);
  var
    y, z, sum, delta, a, b, c, d, n: Cardinal;
    iCounter: Integer;
  begin
    y := V[0];
    z := V[1];
    sum := 0;
    delta := $9E3779B9; // 2654435769;//0x9E3779B9;
    a := KeyArray[0];
    b := KeyArray[1];
    c := KeyArray[2];
    d := KeyArray[3];
    n := 32;
    for iCounter := n downto 1 do begin
      sum := sum + delta;
      y := y + (((z shl 4) + a) xor (z + sum) xor ((z shr 5) + b));
      z := z + (((y shl 4) + c) xor (y + sum) xor ((y shr 5) + d));
    end;
    W[0] := y;
    W[1] := z;
  end;
```

I have tried mundane things like changing all the "+" to "-" however I did not have much hope as I really don't actually understand the code at all.

Comment: This is 32 round XTEA (or a close variation because standard XTEA does a conversion little <-> big endian before and after the loop). There are some open source Pascal/Delphi XTEA implementations available.

Comment: So, what you have to do is **understand the code**. Step through your debugger and look at what's actually happening with variable values.  Your question as it is now looks like "Can you write my code for me?". That is not what this site is for.

Comment: Just for future reference, why would someone have down-voted my question?

Comment: Different folks have their own reasons to DV. Even good questions sometimes get DVs. Those that typically attract a large number of them usually: seem poorly researched, lack important information (especially relevant code), show lack of effort, are confusing. Sometimes you'll be lucky to get a comment giving reasons for a DV (not necessarily by the person who gave the DV). @JanDoggen has suggested why someone might give you a DV. Though imho that would be a bit harsh: Yes you could spend hours step debugging to understand the code. But it's much faster to hope the algorithm is recognised.

Comment: @CraigYoung Thanks for the insight

Comment: It could be just the wording. *I really don't actually understand the code at all* does not sound like you have done much effort. That's why I commented 'start debugging.' If you had written something like "Before I start tracing all this code, does anyone recognize the algorithm?" you would have gotten different reactions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA). Check it out on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm).

Your decryption routine should be something like this (keeping with your naming conventions, etc.):

```
procedure Decipher(var V, W: TintArray);
var
  y, z, sum, delta, a, b, c, d, n: Cardinal;
  iCounter: Integer;
begin
  y := V[0];
  z := V[1];
  sum := $C6EF3720;
  delta := $9E3779B9; // 2654435769;//0x9E3779B9;
  a := KeyArray[0];
  b := KeyArray[1];
  c := KeyArray[2];
  d := KeyArray[3];
  n := 32;
  for iCounter := n downto 1 do begin
    z := z - (((y shl 4) + c) xor (y + sum) xor ((y shr 5) + d));
    y := y - (((z shl 4) + a) xor (z + sum) xor ((z shr 5) + b));
    sum := sum - delta;
  end;
  W[0] := y;
  W[1] := z;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed

Comment: @Donovan, glad to be of help!